# How can I create multiple links between turtles in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

```
breed [ As A ]
breed [ Bs B ]
bs-owns [ stock0 stock1 .... stock5]
```

I created 5 of A and 100 of B, and B owns stock0 to stock5. 
Value of each stock will change randomly from 0 to 10.

I want to create links between A and B according to the value of stocks.
 
For example, If B's value of stock0 is 5, then I want to create 5 links between A00 and Bs.
If B's value of stock1 is 3, then I want to create 3 links between A01 and Bs. How can I do this?

Comment: Not totally sure I understand. If stock0 is 5, do you want to create 5 links between A00 and each B (so there would be `5 * count Bs` links), or a single link to 5 Bs (so there would be just 5 links)?

Comment: I want to creat 5 links between A00 and each B.

Answer (score 3):

NetLogo does not support multiple links between two turtles.* Instead, you can use link-variables to effectively do the same thing. So, make a link variable like:

```
links-own [ stock-value ]
```

then, when create the link, you can do something like:

```
ask Bs [
  create-link-with A00 [ set stock-value stock0 ]
]
```

*This isn't strictly true. You can have multiple links between two turtles as long as the links are of different breeds. But this doesn't help you in the current situation.